# Criando campo com formato peso com duas casas decimais e 3 casas antes da vírgula

Tags: java, swing, formatação

Estou tentando criar um campo "peso", porém estou com alguns problemas.

O peso pode variar de 2 a 3 casas decimais antes do ponto. Por exemplo, poderia ser 80.00 Kg ou 100.00 Kg. Porém, da maneira que eu estou fazendo, ele me obriga a pôr as 3 casas antes do ponto.

Eu também tentei colocar um `setText("00.00");` para o campo não "iniciar" só com o ponto, mais ele não pegou. Como eu posso resolver isso?

```
public class Peso extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Peso t = new Peso();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }

    CampoPeso peso = new CampoPeso();
    JPanel painel = new JPanel();

    public Peso() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Peso:");
        painel.add(label);
        painel.add(peso);
        add(painel);

        setSize(220, 100);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class CampoPeso extends JFormattedTextField {

    public CampoPeso() {
        setColumns(5);
        setText("00.00");
        try {
            MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter("###.##");
            mf.install(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //para pegar o valor
    public Float getValor() {
        return new Float(getText().replace(".", "").replace(",", "."));
    }

    //setar o valor
    public void setValor(Object valor) {
        setText(valor.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer resolver. Qual o problema com o código?

Comment: @Articuno a mascara me obriga sempre a colocar as 3 casas

Comment: @Articuno é que eu não sei como deixa "dinâmico",se eu colocar 2, so vai ate 99kg por exemplo.

Comment: Se o objetivo é limitar o tamanho maximo e não definir um tamanho fixo, então a resposta dessa duplicata resolve o problema.

Comment: mais ai eu posso usar com a mascara ? eu queria criar o campo de uma forma que ele seja separado, entede ? 85.00 por exemplo, naquela resposta so vai limitar a quantidade

Comment: @Articuno a entendo, complicado, ainda sou iniciante, acredito que não consigo fazer uma na mão ainda. Vou ver qual fica melhor então entre as opções ai.

Comment: Tem uma mascara no formato decimal, talvez ela sirva. Só não sei se ela obriga todos os campos, preciso testar aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme solução [desta resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876889/5524514), você pode personalizar a máscara dessa forma:

```
public CampoPeso() {
    setColumns(5);

    setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactory() {

        @Override
        public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
            DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
            format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
            formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
            formatter.setMinimum(0.00);
            formatter.setMaximum(999.99);
            return formatter;
        }

    });

}
```

Resumidamente explicando, estou criando uma máscara numérica decimal, que limita a duas casas fracionárias, valores entre `0,00` a `999,99`.

Funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Fazendo uma pequena alteração, conforme [esta outra resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5054217/5524514), também é possível forçar o "."(ponto) como separador padrão de casas decimais:

```
class CampoPeso extends JFormattedTextField {

    public CampoPeso() {
        setColumns(5);

        setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactory() {

            @Override
            public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
                DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
                format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
                format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
                format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

                DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(getLocale());
                otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');

                format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(otherSymbols);
                NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
                formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
                formatter.setMinimum(0.00);
                formatter.setMaximum(999.99);
                return formatter;
            }

        });

    }

    // para pegar o valor
    public Float getValor() {
        return Float.valueOf(getText());
    }

   (...)

}
```

Vale ressaltar que você precisa alterar seu método `getValor()`, pois agora que o número já vem com ponto como separador, não é preciso mais fazer replace de virgula por ponto.

Comment: muito obrigado !

Comment: onde você definiu que ele deve atribuir virgula?

Comment: @Javinha A combinação de `DecimalFormat` + `NumberFormatter` define que deve ser um numero fracionario separado por virgula.

Comment: e como eu mudo pra ponto ? Porque quando eu pegar esse valor como float,ele não vai aceitar a virgula.

Comment: @Javinha seu código já não faz isso, troca virgula por ponto? Acho que você ta começando a complicar algo que já está meio complicado.

Comment: ele não troca. Eu tentei deixar o replace la, igual vi em uma resposta sua, mais n tem como digitar no campo

Comment: @Javinha como não? No GIF eu to usando exatamente seu código. A única modificação é essa que adicionei na resposta e me permitiu digitar normal.

Comment: @Javinha tenta adaptar a partir dessa resposta do link, se não conseguir, me avisa que depois eu tento modificar a resposta, agora to no celular e fica meio complicado editar. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5054217/5524514

Comment: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(formatString, otherSymbols);
formatString, otherSymbols o que eu passo aqui?

Comment: @Javinha atualizado.